# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=9.0.0.0

Tags: .net, webdeploy

I have VS 2013 Ultimate. My remote server is IIS 7.5 and enabled for remote deployment. I have installed Web Deploy Tool 2.1 through Web Platform Installer 4.6 and it installed successfully.

When I try to validate connection from to remote server from my local machine on Publish tool, I get following error:
"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PubliKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 or one of its dependencies. The system can not find the file specified."

I understand that Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll is missing from my machine. I installed Web Deployment Tool to install this assembly. But that doesn't solve the issue. The assembly is not reflected in my list of available assemblies to add to my project as reference.

Same question has been answered in other threads. But those are not solving my issue.

Any idea to get around this issue?

Regards,
Suraj

Comment: I uninstalled VS 2013 and Web Deploy and reinstalled with Web Deploy 2. That fixed the issue. Weired but worked.

Comment: That's kind of what happened to me. I noticed that the web platform installer installed both Web Deploy 2 and Web Deploy 3.5. I uninstalled both and only installed Web Deploy 3.5 and that fixed my problem.

Comment: thanks. i am finding this since last 2 days. ☺

Comment: I was getting this error when trying to browse Azure sites in Server Explorer. Earlier, I'd uninstalled Web Deploy Tool thinking it was something else and never connected that to my problem. Thanks for this.

Comment: Had this issue with VS 2015. A repair on Web Deploy from the control-panel solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 10):

Web Deloy 3.5 Solve my problem you can  download from  Web Deploy
3.5, from  http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy
Close and  reload your project in VS 2013.
try to validate at connection tab
Publish your site.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, I solved this issue like this:

1. Go to References in VS
2. Right Click, then Add Reference
3. Browse to "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy" *(it should be installed already, if not, download and install from [this link](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).)*
4. Select "Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll" and add it to the project
5. Don't forget to restart and clean & rebuild your project

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2022 (works probably also in earlier versions), the issue was solved by opening the vs installer  (Tools->Get Tools and Features) and then installing the "Web Deploy" component in the "individual components" section.
Use search to find the component.

(After installing the component, I started visual studio one time as an  admin. Maybe its important, maybe not, I have not checked without.).