# Error while Publishing Web App in Visual Studio Professional 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to publish my Web App in Visual Studio Professional 2013 but getting the following error
[image: Error Message]

I got the same question asked over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754565/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-web-deployment-version-9-0-0-0) but no useful answer.
Can anyone please help

Comment: which .net version are you using

Comment: did the problem solved

Comment: @anand I am usng 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will be using older version, that was having an issue. refer detail [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684699/could-not-find-file-or-assembly-microsoft-web-deployment-tracing-with-web-deploy)

Install the [newer web deployment tool](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy), should work.

Answer (score 2):

which .net version are you using.
check `web deploy version`. if vs has 2 web deploy version, the vs get confuse to take which version. If it has 2 version, just uninstall vs and then instal it along with web deploy. if the Vs has one 1 web deploy version, you uninstall and install the web deploy. It will rectify your problem i hope.
You can refer [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754565/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-web-deployment-version-9-0-0-0)

Comment: this problem happens in all versions

Answer (score 1):

Check if version 9.0.0.0 of the assembly is installed in GAC. (from the VS2013 developer command prompt) `gacutil /l Microsoft.Web.Deployment`. Issues like this have occurred in the past where things worked, then after installing an update (or trying to install one) then reports of missing dlls, like nuget, occur.

The usual course of action is to repair the Visual Studio installation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your publish profile. Delete the pubxml file located bellow Properties folder in your project and then create a new publish profile.

Comment: Did that number of times but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when older project runs into the new .NET Framework, for that you have to do the following.

Right Click on your project name->select **Property Pages** -> Click **Build** from the menu-> then select **Target Framework .Net framework 4.5** or your current using framework..

Comment: Framewrok is properly set

Answer (score 0):

"Could not load file or assembly" means the required file (of that mentioned version) is not available in the assembly (nor in the registry). All you gotta to do is to ensure this same is installed properly that would allow you to proceed further. The other things to ensure is the latest framework installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Think you have some errors happen when to install or update Visual 2013, so you can reinstall again and this error will be fixed.